# Change font size of specific columns

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, xslt

How can the font size of a specific column in a list be changed? The missing design view in SPD2013 does not help with that...
I do not have access a style library, because it's apparantly only existing on the top level site of a site collection? This seems to kill my approach with XSLT.

Are there any other options to change the style of a view?

Comment: Wack some CSS on the page and use the n-th Child CSS selectors to target your column

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I looked up nth-child css, but how do I target the specific columns? Do I need to get something from the view's *.aspx?

Comment: The 30 CSS selectors you must memorize: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can add a script editor, you can do something like this:

[image]

So the heading is complete 20px. If you want this for only one column you have to use the developer tools (F12) to find your element.

Hope this gives you a starting point.

**Update 1:**

[image]

Here where I found the class:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I assume it's possible to change the font of the entries, too? E.g. lorem1 and lorem2.

Comment: yes, see my update