# Apply color for list column

Tags: custom-list

I have four columns:

1. FirstName
2. LastName
3. Date
4. Birthday

I want to apply color and font for the `FirstName` column data only, how can this be done?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 or 2010?

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013, You can try **Client Side Rendering**. You just need to override the display template of `FirstName`. For example,

```
Templates: {
    Fields: {
        "FirstName": {
            View: function(ctx) {
                var FirstName = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
                return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + FirstName + "</span>";;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## CSR HELP

- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)
- [Client-side rendering (JS Link) code samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)
- [SharePoint CSR Live Edit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)

Comment: Where we need to put the code

Comment: Use Cisar.... It will add the code to your desired view

Comment: See this post for using Cisar http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/162286/21421

Comment: Cisar means , please give me exactly where we need to change

Comment: Cisar is chrome extension **This extension is for SharePoint Developers. It makes process of creating SharePoint Client Side Rendering customizations many times faster. The customizations will be applied as-you-type to the underlying SharePoint page. Cisar provides CSR-tailored intellisense and tight integration with the underlying page**

Comment: Let me know for more help...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sharepoint Designer for this.

SharePoind Designer > Site and Libraries > Right click the View > Edit File in Advanced Mode

Conditional Formatting in Ribbon

There you find your settings.

For example:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2011/10/20/sharepoint-lists-conditional-formatting-using-sharepoint-designer-2010.aspx

Comment: Note that this will not work for SP2013.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is with CSR (see Atish Dipongkor's answer). Another way would be overwriting the CSS with a content editor. [See the answer/comments of this question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163507/change-font-size-of-specific-columns).

Answer (score 0):

While creating a list column, you can give the below formula to change the list html property.

```
="<DIV style='color:yellow'></DIV>"
```

The above code will change your column background color as yellow.

Like this you can alter the column html properties.

Hope it resolves your problem.